# Seeing duplicate cookie response headers

Tags: magento-1.9, header, cookie, request

When looking at the request headers for my Magento 1 site I can see it has 2 cookie request headers.

```
Set-Cookie:frontend=3dt1aedashghghg1vr9ua0tghms7; expires=Fri, 20-Oct-2017 07:52:20 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=www.example.com; secure; httponly
Set-Cookie:cookiesEnabled=1; expires=Fri, 20-Oct-2017 06:52:50 GMT; Max-Age=30
```

Please could someone advise if this is normal and if its not the best way to solve this issue

Comment: there are no duplicate here... https://www.google.ie/search?q=duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's normal.
`frontend` is your frontend session cookie
`cookiesEnabled` is the cookie that states you agreed that the website can store cookies on your browser (you know that EU law that does not make much sense).